# Is it possible to pass more number of parameters on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

eg:
This is usual parameters passing,

```
$this->template->write_view('content','admin/content',$data, TRUE);
```

My question is can we add more no of $data like mentioned below:

```
$this->template->write_view('content','admin/content',$data1, $data2, TRUE);
```

can anyone help me with it???

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this:

```
$this->template->write_view('content','admin/content',$data, TRUE);
```

and have `$data` look like this:

```
$data = array(
  'first' => array(
    'something',
    'something else'
  ),
  'second' => array(
    'more data' => 'even more',
    'something again'
  ),
  'something',
  'something else'
);
```

This way, instead of having `$data1` and `$data2`, you could use `$first` or `$second` when you use it on the view. Then `$first['something']` if it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to make changes to Template parser class to do this, on the easy side, you can try this, combine when passing, and seprate when rendering in view

```
$data = [ $data1, $data2 ];

write_view('content', 'admin/content', $data, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an array and then you can put data on that array and pass them with parameter . Try with the following sample format:

```
    $data = array(); //array declaration 
    $data['message1'] = 'Save Corner Information Successfully !'; //put data on variable 'message1'
    $data['message2'] = 'Save Corner Information Successfully !'; 
    $data['message3'] = 'Save Corner Information Successfully !';
```

$this->template->write_view('content','admin/content',$data, TRUE);